# The choice of cross or traverse

Tags: verbs

I write and review technical reports.  We need help answering a question regarding the subtle difference in using the word cross or the word traverse in sentences.  For instance:

A pipeline crosses the property.
A pipeline traverses the property.

It is my impression that cross would be the better choice.  To me, traverse implies the act of moving back and forth, or traveling, where cross implies something from point A to B.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One point about *traverse* is that it can be directly used as a noun, whereas you must use *crossing* to "nounify" *cross*.

Comment: It is a good question, I have a sense that _'traversing'_ has more heroic dimensions than simply _'crossing'_,  but as JEL points out, we need some 'authority' to back up an answer, or even a comment.  Meanwhile, here's an Ngram which suggests _'cross'_ or _'crossing'_ might be what you'd expect to find in this sort of case: http://tinyurl.com/ju3zsu5

Answer (score 1):

I like your impression. Consider traversing a street versus crossing a street. Traversing implies you are moving along the street or getting to all the points the street contains whereas crossing implies you have a start point and an end point and the street obstructs you along the way somehow.

Edit: The "better choice" would depend on the pipeline itself. Traverse, as a verb, covers more cases than does cross. The best choice would be the more specific "cross" if the pipe crosses from one side to the other. If it winds through the property, traverse would be a better option.

Comment: Your comments in your edit fit my impression of usage as well.  Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The choice is context-dependent. For example, rephrasing your instances,

> A pipeline crosses property A, entering property B at coordinates ....

and

> A pipeline traverses property A, entering the north pasture at coordinate X and exiting at coordinate Y to enter property B at coordinate Z.

Thus, while 'traverse' may simply be used to mean 'cross', and the other way around, the difference between the terms allows more precise phrasing depending on context and the precise nuances of the meaning you intend to convey.

Here are some dictionary definitions. The contrast may make the distinction more comprehensible:

> **traverse**, *v. trans.*
>   ... to pass or journey across, over, or through; to pass through (a region) from side to side, or from end to end ....
>
> **cross**, *v. trans.*
>   ....
>   8. To pass over a line, boundary, river, channel, etc.; to pass from one side to the other of any space.
>   ....
>   9. a. Of things: to extend across from side to side.

(Definitions from the [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/).)

Thus, when the connotations highlighted by the context emphasize *passage* or *travel* from place to place, as opposed to the mere fact of extending from side to side of a place, 'traverse' is the most appropriate choice.

If, on the other hand, the connotations highlighted by the context only include the fact of the pipeline going from one side of the property to the other, 'cross' would be the more appropriate term.

The choice between the terms may not be an easy one, and depends on the intentions of the author, in that 'traverse' will tend to bring the readers' attention to the place that is crossed more than 'cross', which will refer the readers' attention more to the mere fact of the crossing.

My entire explanation, and the definitions cited, should be interpreted as re-inforcing your impression

> ... To me, traverse implies the act of moving back and forth, or *traveling*, where cross implies something from point A to B.

Observe also that 'traverse' has a specialized or technical sense in surveying and documents pertaining to surveying:

> **traverse**, *v.*
>   7. *Surveying.* To determine the positions of points on the earth's surface by measuring the lengths and azimuths of a connected series of straight lines; to make or execute a traverse (traverse n. 3) of (a region); to delimit (an area) by thus determining the position of points on its boundaries; to trace the course of (a road, river, etc.) in this way.

(op. cit.)

The noun sense (3) referred to in the special verbal sense of 'traverse' is this:

> **traverse**, *n.*
>   3. *Surveying.* A single line of survey carried across a region or through a narrow strip of country, by measuring the lengths and azimuths of a connected series of straight lines; used either where there is no general trigonometrical survey, or in filling up the details of one. Also, a tract of country so surveyed.

(op. cit.)

These last definitions may be especially pertinent if you are writing and reviewing technical documents that use terms from surveying. In the case where you are reviewing such documents, you should be sure to leave unchanged any technical terms provided by specialists.

Comment: But of course if you're on skis it's always *traverse*.

Answer (score -1):

In most non-technical English, a pipeline crosses a property, and "traverse" in such a case would be more formal/technical just for its own sake.

A "traverse" over (or "traversing") some terrain usually contains the implication that it is both long and difficult (often used in mountaineering and similar adventurous pursuits), rather than just passing through or over a property.

So unless there are other very good reasons to use *traverse*, I would recommend "crosses the property".